# Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a solution to this validation error.

I am pretty new to coding, any help would be great.

```html
<div style="padding-top: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <ul class="ui-listview">
    <li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-hover-a ui-btn-up-a ui-li-has-count ui-li-count">
      <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ">
        <div class="ui-btn-text"> <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="/link/?id=1234"> <span class="lady img" style="float: left;"> <img class="ui-li-thumb" style="border: 0px;" src="https://images.test.com/images/inserat/img/01k.jpg" alt="Inserat" title="Inserat" /> </span>
          <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong>City</strong></p>
          <p class="ui-li-desc">Street</p>
          <h4 class="ui-li-heading">Name</h4>
          <p class="ui-li-desc">Text, Text, ...</p>
          </a> </div>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"> </span> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What validator are you using?

Comment: @majas Since the piece of code you posted here won't trigger the error message by itself, can you provide a [mcve] that does?

Comment: @MrLister yes right i didn't pay attention to the whole structure

Comment: I take the W3C Validator